# How can I let a user change Knowledge Settings without giving full admin rights?

Tags: knowledge, permission-sets

I have a permission set for users to manage all Knowledge setup, but even with the 'Manage Knowledge' permission, they are not allowed to edit knowledge settings. Is there a permission that I'm missing here or is this only available for administrators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**“Customize Application”** Permission also required to allow user to edit Knowledge setting.